# Porque usar o Container de DI do asp.net core em conjunto com OnConfiguring o Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Em muitos projetos percebo que as pessoas tendem a passar a connection string tanto por injeção de dependência quanto por optionsBuilder na sobreposição do método OnConfiguring.... Qual o sentido de usar ambos ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: `Qual o sentido de usar ambos ao mesmo tempo?` não precisa, desnecesário, ou um ou outro. Preferível `DI` deixando as configurações no `appsettings.json` para ficar flexível a sua instalação no servidor e fácil a manipulação na sua DI.

Comment: É dessa maneira que penso